# Get FB likes count for specific URL and page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

This is a two questions in one.

1. Is it possible to get the likes count to a specific page inside a website? As in if there's a like button without a specific target url, likes will be given to the address in the `window.location.href`; can this number be retrieved without an API key?
2. Is it possible to get the official Facebook page/page id if I only have the URL of the website? If i only have the URL / domain name (coca-cola.com), can I get the facebook page which is https://www.facebook.com/cocacola?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check the like count of a website by calling the Graph like the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.your-website.com/the-url-or-so

To your Question if you can get a Facebook Page if you are the owner of the Business:

Yes! Some times ago I've read an article posted by Facebook where this is described. If you are the owner of a company/business/brand you can ask facebook for the page transfer to your account. For that you must be the owner and your business is really large. When the names of the companies are the same you must have to one which is more popular.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the likes count to a specific page inside a website?

If that page is in the Open Graph, yes.

> Is it possible to get the official Facebook page/page id if I only have the URL of the website?

No, because there is no such thing. No one is *obligated* to have a FB fan page for their business, organization or whatever.