# Is it possible to get Facebook likes for any page other than FQL API?

Tags: facebook

I've read this post:

[Get FB likes count for specific URL and page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919501/get-fb-likes-count-for-specific-url-and-page)

But when I visit that URL, I got:

`(#4) Application request limit reached`.

I am using a VPN connection because Facebook has been blocked in China. I am not sure whether this is related. Anyway I can still see all the likes on any pages.

Is there any other approaches I can try?

Comment: Add your access token to the request

Comment: what's an access token? It's like a Facebook App Token for developers?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

Basically, you have to create your own app and use the app_id with the app_secret concatenated by a pipe symbol like this:

```
{app_id}|{app_secret}
```

which yields in

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}&ids=http://www.your-website.com/
```